# Extract a node value from json response in shell

Tags: shell, unix

I have the following json response

{"data":{"serverPort":0,"runId":7008,"runAction":false,"runStatus":"started"},"total":1,"success":true}

Wanted to retrieve the value of runStatus.
How can i do this using grep command

Answer (score 2):

Mangling JSON with `grep` may not be the right way to go. To work with JSON on the command line, I would recommend to use the `jq` utility (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ echo '{"data":{"serverPort":0,"runId":7008,"runAction":false,"runStatus":"started"},"total":1,"success":true}' | jq '.data.runStatus'
"started"
```

Other solutions have been discussed here: [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools). For example, you could use `python` if that is available to you:

```
$ echo '{"data":{"serverPort":0,"runId":7008,"runAction":false,"runStatus":"started"},"total":1,"success":true}' | python3 -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['data']['runStatus'])"
started
```

However, extracting a nested value from JSON using just UNIX tools might be tricky.

Comment: I dont have jq installed in my client machine. Hence tried for grep command. Any other option to extract that node value

Comment: Extracting a nested value from JSON using just UNIX tools might be tricky, I have added another example using `python` and a link for further reading